# _rawValidators of null on adding new FormGroup dynamicly

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to create a dynamic form and push some formGoups to the form, when a button is clicked.

here is some (reduced) code..
creating the form

```
form: FormGroup;
influencer: FormArray;
collaborations: FormArray;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    _id: ['', Validators.required],
    influencer: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });
}
```

creating influencer form group and collaboration group

```
createInfluencer() {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    collaborations: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}

createCollaboration(){
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    logoUrl: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

Button events to create the groups:

```
addInfluencer(): void {
  this.influencer = this.form.get('influencer') as FormArray;
  this.influencer.push(this.createInfluencer());
}

addCollaboration(index): void {
  const influencer = this.form.get('influencer') as FormArray;
  this.collaborations = influencer.controls[index].get('collaborations') as FormArray;
  this.collaborations.push(this.createCollaboration());
}
```

Creating Influencer Group works nice, but on creating a collaboration group i`m getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_rawValidators' of null
```

And i not unterstand why this occurs. Can someone explain why the error occurs?

Comment: collaboration is dependent on Influencer so you need to make sure when you call `addCollaboration(index)` the Influencer already called and has form array.

Comment: @KamranKhatti the button for creatin collaborations is in the influencer template. so there is no button if there is no influencer

Comment: can you create a stackblitz and reproduce the issue there it will help to fix there?

Comment: @KamranKhatti you got me :) while building it on stackblitz i saw that a formGroupName in the template not covers all fields...didnt see it for 2 hours....thank you and i go sleep

Comment: Try making your forms without `Validators.required`. If this works, then you can add the validations manually.